# Blender 3.6 is unwrapping simple meshes at an angle

Tags: uv

The latest version of blender introduced a UV overhaul that appears to work fantastically for complex meshes, but not so well for simple meshes anymore. Cubes and planes now unwrap at an angle to use maximum space on the UV map, but this is not usable for texturing, where the unwrapping methods in 3.5 and earlier did this beautifully.

How can this rotation be corrected, or the new UV unwrapping be temporarily disabled?

**Blender 3.5**
[image: Blender 3.5 screenshot]

**And the same operation in Blender 3.6.1:**
[image]

A workaround to this is to align the UV by clicking in the menu UV > Align Rotation, and then with Constrain to Image Bounds selected, scale the UV map to force it to fit.

Comment: Good question - I hadn't noticed the change until you mentioned it.

Comment: i just tried it on 3.5 & 3.6. interesting. should this not be reported as a bug? you cannot correct it, because it is the program code that changed, but fortunately you have your workaround with *UV > Align Rotation*

Comment: Something odd that I've found is if I create a similar plane to the one in the images and the Generate UVs option is checked, when I go to the UV Editing workspace it is unwrapped without any rotation and fills the map. I can create a new UV map of some other size and the mapping still fills the area. If I try an unwrap method from the U menu, the only option that gives a UV like in the 3.5 image is Cube Projection. The Unwrap and Smart UV Project give the rotated map as shown above.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie   There are (enough?) quick ways to project a _simple_ mesh aligned to UV's straight from the top-level menu, would you really call this a bug? I'd just call it a mode of operation.. it's a  dev. **choice**  of priority for the default, easily overridden..?

Comment: imho as a dev myself i would consider it as a bug, i think they accidenctally broke this functionality because usually a texture would not be aligned diagonal. at least i dont see any advantage to this. it introduced more of an inconvenience and i doubt the devs intended this. of course i could be wrong, just my opinion :)