# Prevent rotated UV islands when unwrapping a quad sphere

Tags: uv

I've created a quad sphere using several different methods (sphere -> subdiv surface; sphere -> subdiv surface -> cast). I then marked 12 seams and tried unwrapping it using several methods. The best result for my purposes I get using the regular "unwrap" method. However, the generated UV islands are slightly rotated. Is there a way to prevent that? I Googled a bit and found that I could "pin" certain nodes. But what I tried, I couldn't get nice UV islands. Below I've added some screenshots of my situation. Does anybody know how I could get a result matching the last screenshot?

Here's my result. As you can see the islands are slightly rotated:
[image: My UV islands]

Here are the seams I have defined:
[image: My seams]

And here's the result I'd like to get. This UV I got from an already properly unwrapped triangle-based model I got from the internet:
[image: Proper island layout]

Comment: [I don't think you can change blender's behavior on that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298264/blender-3-6-is-unwrapping-simple-meshes-at-an-angle) You can however try this, create a cube, mark all edges as seems. Then unwrap it to get 6 squares on the UV Editor. Then subdivide the cube __and then__ cast to sphere. that way you also don't have rounded square on your UV. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298264/blender-3-6-is-unwrapping-simple-meshes-at-an-angle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it myself. I installed the `Add Mesh: Extra Objects` extension that comes with Blender. Then I created a new quad sphere by doing `Add -> Round Cube`. I expanded the properties dialog that appears in the lower left of Blender and selected `Quadsphere` from the `Operator Presets` dropdown. When you mark the proper seams (see my opening post) and unwrap it, the UV islands appear straight. I don't know why this differs from my own method, but at least it's working.

[image: Add Round Cube dialog]

[image: Proper straight UV islands]